# Spark SQL: put the conditional count result into a new column

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the data like this:

```
|  id  |  action  |
|   1  | increase |
|   2  | increase |
|   1  | increase |
|   1  | decrease |
|   3  | decrease |
```

I want to get the result

```
|  id  | increase | decrease |
|   1  |     2    |     1    |
|   2  |     1    |     0    |
|   3  |     0    |     1    |
```

I try something like, althouth it is wrong:

```
val result = data.groupBy($"id").withColumn("increase", data("action").where(" action == 'increase' ").count).withColumn("decrease", data("action").where(" decrease == 'view' ").count)

35: error: value withColumn is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.GroupedData
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `groupBy.pivot`, and use `count` as the aggregation function:

```
df.groupBy("id").pivot("action").agg(count($"action")).na.fill(0).show
+---+--------+--------+
| id|decrease|increase|
+---+--------+--------+
|  1|       1|       2|
|  3|       1|       0|
|  2|       0|       1|
+---+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks! Solve the problem!